# Creating a brand attribute as a variable

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, javascript, api

I have a script below where I dynamically need to replace two values and I can't get it to work.

The values can be found as Wooccomerce product attribute values on the product page.

For instance, see the below.

Brand| "Ashley"

MPN| "234gty"

I intend to pull the values of each attribute, "Ashley" and "234gty"  and use them as variables to fill in the script below.

```
       var ccs_cc_args = ccs_cc_args || [];
       
       // Main Product Page
       ccs_cc_args.push(['cpn', '']);
       ccs_cc_args.push(['mf', '$brand']);
       ccs_cc_args.push(['pn', '$mpn']);
       ccs_cc_args.push(['upcean', 'UPC_EAN_CODE']);
       ccs_cc_args.push(['ccid', 'CATALOG_CODE']);
       ccs_cc_args.push(['lang', 'LANGUAGE']);
       ccs_cc_args.push(['market', 'MARKET']);
       
       (function () {
          var o = ccs_cc_args; o.push(['_SKey', '3f1b897a']); o.push(['_ZoneId', '6ce9a32538']);
          var sc = document.createElement('script'); sc.type = 'text/javascript'; sc.async = true;
          sc.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'cdn.cnetcontent.com/jsc/h.js';
          var n = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; n.parentNode.insertBefore(sc, n);
       })();
```

I've tried adding the following to the footer.php and functions.php and echo to the product page with no luck.

```
global $product;

$mpn = array_shift( wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, 'pa_mpn', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) ) );

$brand = array_shift( wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, 'pa_brand', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) ) );
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this is a WP question and not a general javascript/PHP question, if you want to output a PHP variable to the browser you do it the same way wether it appears inside a HTML tag or in javascript, your JS runs only on the browser not the server so none of that javascript is considered code and those variables are not substituted, they're just the ltieral text `$mpn` the same as `<p>$mpn</p>` doesn't work, you would need `<p><?php echo $mpn; ?></p>` instead

Comment: Also, WooCommerce questions are off topic here, this is not a place to get WooCommerce help, although as I mentioned in the previous comment I suspect your problem has nothing to do with WooCommerce or WordPress